# Kendo UI treemap json binding

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, treemap

I have been trying to build a very simple treemap(no hierarchy) using KendoUI, by providing it some json  data as a datasource. This should have been very straightforward and simple as it's a common use-case. However, I am having no luck with it, after spending hours on it.

I tried this :

```html
<body>
<div id="treemap"></div> 
<script> 
var data = [
    {
    name: "foo123",
    value: 10
    },
    {
    name: "foo234",
    value: 20
    }
   ];
$("#treemap").kendoTreeMap({
dataSource: data,
valueField: "value",
textField: "name"
});
</script>
</body>
```

Any suggestions on what I may be missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/14-05-01/the-kendo-ui-q2-2014-roadmap-is-out!) "TreeMap is a visualization for hierarchical":

> TreeMapping is a visualization for hierarchical data which uses nested
>   rectangles. Each rectangle's size and color is related to the
>   structure of the data, allowing you to more easily identify trends and
>   patterns

So try to add a "root" level that wraps your two elements:

```html
<body>
    <div id="treemap"></div>
    <script>
        var data = [{
            name: "foo",
            value: 1,
            items: [{
                name: "foo123",
                value: 10
            },
            {
                name: "foo234",
                value: 20
            }]
        }];
        $("#treemap").kendoTreeMap({
            dataSource: data,
            valueField: "value",
            textField: "name"
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I wasn't aware that I can represent only hierarchical data in KendoUI treemap. I had come across this example for colors in the documentation (http://dojo.telerik.com/eFAWI) which has no hierarchical structure, and so was misleading.